# Getting data from identical named fields in two different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem selecting data from 2 different tables.
Table1 and Table2 both have fields 'ID' and 'Categories'

I'm trying to get all 'ID''s where 'Categories' = 100001

I can do it from Table1 as so:

```
$ids = @mysql_values('SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Live = 1 AND Categories = 100001 ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 20');
```

This works.

But when I try a join using my limited knowledge, it doesn't work. This is my joined query that doesn't work but I can't see why:

```
$ids = @mysql_values('SELECT Table1.ID, Table2.ID FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Live = 1 AND Categories = 100001 ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 20');
```

Any help appreciated. I have looked at other examples and tried them but to no avail.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `UNION`:

```
SELECT ID, Categories
FROM Table1
WHERE Live = 1 AND Categories = 100001
UNION
SELECT ID, Categories
FROM Table2
WHERE Live = 1 AND Categories = 100001
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 20;
```

Or, if you prefer to have the condition only once:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Categories
    FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT ID, Categories
    FROM Table2)
WHERE Live = 1 AND Categories = 100001
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Thank you all, all these answers helped but I went with the UNION (tried them all and got them all to work eventually but settled with the union. Not sure of the pros and cons to each method, but thanks all

Answer (score 2):

This is simply equivalent of `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table2.ID 
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE Live = 1 
  AND Categories = 100001 
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 20
```

You probably want to `JOIN` tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.<pk> = t2.<fk>     -- you need to join both tables
WHERE Live = 1             -- add t1.Live/t2.Live dependent on table
  AND Categories = 100001  -- same as above
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are on the right track.

Since the problem is both tables have `categories` column, you would want to have something like the below:

```
$ids = @mysql_values('SELECT Table1.ID, Table2.ID FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Live = 1 AND 100001 IN (Table1.Categories, Table2.Categories) ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 20');
```

Notice how i changed `Categories = 100001` to `100001 IN (Table1.Categories, Table2.Categories)`